# How to run change detection (update template) for @Input value when previous value same as current value?

Tags: angular, ngrx

How to run change detection (update template) for @Input value when previous value same as current value?

DEMO: https://plnkr.co/edit/Rvz2ElLjM20R3nC6ZQWt?p=preview

I'm using `ngrx`.

Use case:
I want to set default value for input after blur event, if input value is empty.

Input:

```
        <input 
            id="format" 
            class="form-control" 
            type="text" 
            [value]="inputValue" 
            (keyup)="keyup$.next($event.target.value)"
            (blur)="blur$.next($event.target.value)"
        >
```

`[value]="inputValue"` - `@Input` value of dumb component, taken from `store -> format`.
I take the value from the `store` in this way:

```
//main component

//template
template: `<format-input [inputValue]="format$ | async" (outputValue)="updateFormat($event)"></format-input>`

this.format$ = this.store.let(getFormat());

//form-reduser.ts
export function getFormat () {
    return (state$: Observable<GeneratorFormState>) => state$
        .map(s => s.format);
}
```

Both `keyup` and `blur` run action `updateFormat`.

My problem is what after `blur` event `[value]="inputValue"`will not update if value, which was inserted in the `store` was the same as previous `store` value.

For example:

1) store value: 22 => input value: 22 => clearing (cut) input value => blur event => input is empty, setting default value (1) to the store => store value: 1 => input value: 1

2) store value: 1 => input value: 1 => clearing (cut) input value => blur event => input is empty, setting default value (1) to the store => store value: 1 => input value: '' (empty)

So, how i can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your problem but this might be what you're looking for

Import `ChangeDetectorRef` and call `cdRef.detectChanges()` after before the values is set to the old value.

Comment: I added demo https://plnkr.co/edit/Rvz2ElLjM20R3nC6ZQWt?p=preview

2 components: parent and DunbInput.

Comment: How do I reproduce? What is the expected behavior?

Comment: 2 components: parent and DunbInput. 

Parent component value changes only on DumbInput `blur` event.

When input value in template is `1` and we clearing input value - result value is sending back to parent component through `@Output()`, then sending back to `DumbInput` through [inputValue] `@Input()`, but because old `inputValue` and current `inputValue` is the same (`1`) - visible input value in template is `''` (empty value), because `cangeDetection` was not triggered

Comment: And what is the expected behavior?

Comment: In two words:
enter in input `123`, then click outside of the input.
parent value will be `123`.

Then delete all input content and click again outside of the input - parent value will be set as `DEFAULT_VALUE` (`1`) and input will be updated instantly with default value.

Then delete input value (`1`) again - parent value will be set as `DEFAULT_VALUE` (`1`) but input value will not updated with default value and will be empty `''` because previous `@Input()` value was been the same as current `@Input()` value (`1`)

Comment: AFAIK there is no way than setting a different value, invoking change detection imperatively and then setting the value back to the desired value.

Comment: can you provide any example how to do it nice? maybe any workaround?

Comment: Sorry, your example is to complicated to dive in fully the last day before vacation. I had a similar issue a while ago. Where the value was set to `false` and back to `true` before any change detection could run. You just need to inject `ChangeDetectorRef` and call `detectChanges()` to make it run change detection.